# How to configure reporting options when using dalekjs with grunt?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, gruntjs, integration-testing, dalekjs

i have configured followung Gruntmodule for DalekJS:

```
module.exports = {
  dalek: {
    options: {
      browser: ['phantomjs'],
      reporter: ['html', 'junit', 'json'],--> I also tried without this line
      dalekfile: true
    },
    files: {
      src: ['tests/gui/dalekjs/dakektest.js']
    }
  }
};
```

I have a Dalekfile in the same folder as the configured module (i have a splitted gruntfile! see `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/?redirect_from_locale=de`):
Dalekfile.json:

```
{
  "reporter": ["console", "junit", "html", "json"],--> I also tried without this line
  "html-reporter": {
    "dest": "C:/my/path/tests/gui/dalekjs/report"
  },
  "junit-reporter": {
    "dest": "C:/my/path/tests/gui/dalekjs/report/report.xml"
  },
  "json-reporter": {
    "dest": "C:/my/path/tests/gui/dalekjs/report/report.json"
  }
}
```

After executing `grunt` my tests are executed successfully.

But if i check the custom path there is no report. It creates the report in the same folder of the Gruntfile.js so --> gruntfilefolder/report/dalek/

When executing the Dalektest over ther console with dalek dalektest.js the reports are created successfully. --> I installed the reporting plugins as described in the dalek docs!

Is there anyone who can tell me, why the custom path is not used?

Versions:
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.4
grunt-dalek 0.2.0

Cheers izocan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in a google groups discussion here: [How to configure reporting options when using dalekjs with grunt?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dalekjs/6FXtXk4jhy4)